# How to make sinon mock return different objects on different calls?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon, spy

```
 mock = sinon.mock();
 mock.exactly(2);
 mock.callsArgWith(1, m1);
 mock.callsArgWith(1, m2);
```

Here in my test, m2 is overriding m1. I want to return m1 in my first call and m2 in my second call.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`onCall(n)`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/stubs/#stuboncalln-added-in-v18) (or the aliases [`onFirstCall`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/stubs/#stubonfirstcall), [`onSecondCall`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/stubs/#stubonsecondcall), and [`onThirdCall`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/stubs/#stubonthirdcall)) to define the behavior on the *nth* call:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

test('mock returns different objects on different calls', () => {
  const m1 = { id: 1 }
  const m2 = { id: 2 }

  const mock = sinon.mock();
  mock.exactly(2);
  mock
    .onFirstCall().callsArgWith(1, m1)    // first call calls its second arg with m1
    .onSecondCall().callsArgWith(1, m2);  // second call calls its second arg with m2

  const spy = sinon.spy();
  mock('arg0', spy);  // spy should be called with m1
  mock('arg0', spy);  // spy should be called with m2

  sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(spy.getCall(0), m1);  // SUCCESS
  sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(spy.getCall(1), m2);  // SUCCESS
  mock.verify();  // SUCCESS
});
```